# Want to add retrieved data from django DB to my html option tag

Tags: html, django

I want to retrieve data from Django DB and add it to HTML Option tag to show drop down list

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Home.models import Train, LoadStation

def LoadData(request):
    stations = LoadStation.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Home/finalproject.html', {'stations': stations})
```

## finalproject.html

```
<select name="Source_Station" style="width:20%; border: 3px solid red;" id="txt1" onchange="{% url 'Home:LoadData' %}">
    {% for data in stations %}
        <option value="{{ data.Station_Name }}">{{ data.Station_Name }} 
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Expected Output : Drop down  list filled with data in LoadStation Table.

Actual Output : Option Box is empty.

Comment: Can you show your `LoadStation` model?

Comment: class LoadStation(models.Model): <br/>
    Station_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Comment: The code looks OK to me; try a debugger or print out the number of records in the view and in the template to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: When you try to `print(stations)` in your LoadData view, what's the output?

Comment: @Endre onchange event is not occuring while on mouseclick on <select> tag

Comment: @Paolo  No record is printing there cause event not occuring

Comment: Why do you have the `LoadData` in your `onchange` attribute? You dont' really need that. Since you're already passing `stations` object into your template when you're rendering it.